# How to instantiate a generic record with explicit type parameters?

Tags: generics, f#, algebraic-data-types

I want to explicitly provide type parameters when I instantiate a generic record. To put in in another words, given a `RecordType<'T1, 'T2, 'T3>`, I want create an instance of `RecordType<'T1, 'T2, 'T3>` with some fixed `'T1`, `'T2` and `'T3` by specifying those generic parameters. Is there a way to do that in F#?

I see three cases where it's useful:

1. **Instantiating a record when there's more than one generic type with the same name**

   Assume that we have following record definitions:

   ```
   type SimpleGenericRecord<'T1, 'T2> = {
       f1 : 'T1 -> 'T2
   }

   type SimpleGenericRecord<'T> = {
       f1 : 'T -> 'T
   }
   ```

   I easily construct instances of `SimpleGenericRecord<'T>` which was
   defined last:

   ```
   let record = {
       f1 = fun (x: int) -> 0
   } 

   let record1 = {
       SimpleGenericRecord.f1 = fun (x: int) -> 0
   }
   ```

   Following attempts to create `SimpleGenericRecord<int, int>` give
   compile errors:

   ```
   let record2 = {
       SimpleGenericRecord<int, int>.f1 = fun (x: int) -> 0
   }

   let record3 = {
       SimpleGenericRecord<_, _>.f1 = fun (x: int) -> 0
   }
   ```

   I know that having the same record name for two types might be not the best idea, nevertheless, I think that language should give me a way to use both types.
2. **Documenting record types**

   [F# reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/records) says:

   > Don't use the DefaultValue attribute with record fields. A better
   >   approach is to define default instances of records with fields that
   >   are initialized to default values and then use a copy and update
   >   record expression to set any fields that differ from the default
   >   values.

   Following that piece of advice, I would like to define default instances of records and, since they are part of a public API, document their types.
3. **Helping in type inference**

   Generic parameters of a record type could be used to infer types of record's values.

   Assume that I have:

   ```
   type RecordWithSomeComplexType<'T> = {
       t1 : int -> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, 'T> // some long type signature
   }
   ```

   and I want to instantiate it. If I don't provide any type annotations, record values will be as as general as possible, e.g.

   ```
   let record4 = {
       RecordWithSomeComplexType.t1 = failwith "Intentionally failing"
   }
   ```

   has type

   ```
   int -> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, obj>
   ```

   I can force a record to be of a certain type (e.g. `RecordWithSomeComplexType<string>`), but in that case I need to write full type of certain value, e.g.

   ```
   let failing = {
       RecordWithSomeComplexType.t1 = 
           failwith "Intentionally failing"  :> int -> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, string> 
           // I don't want to provide a full type of a value here
   }
   ```

   If compiler knew that I want to `RecordWithSomeComplexType<string>`, it could infer value's signature.

Comment: What compile errors do you get?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin "Field bindings must have the form 'id = expr;'".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add type annotation pretty much anywhere

```
let record2 : SimpleGenericRecord<_, _> = {
    f1 = fun (x: int) -> 0
}

// alternative
let record2 =
  ({
    f1 = fun (x: int) -> 0
  } : SimpleGenericRecord<_, _>)
```

And for the longer case you can write an alias type to ease things

```
type Alias<'T> = int -> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, 'T>

let record4 = {
  t1 = (failwith "Intentionally failing" : Alias<string>)
}
```

*Note that record4 evaluation will raise the exception instantly because it isn't delayed*

Comment: thanks. That was a stupid question. Regarding failwith - I simply used it because it is well known function and has a type which can be narrowed.